# Is there a strpad function in vim

Tags: vim

Is there an in-built function in vim that lengthens a string to a certain amount.

For example

```
let l:some_string   = "abcd"
let l:padded_string = strpad(l:some_string, 10)

" now: strlen(l:some_string) == 10, 
"      l:some_string == "abcd      "
```

I am looking for a function that I could use instead of the strpad above.

Thanks
Rene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to play with repeat:

```
:let str .= repeat(' ', 10-strlen(str))
```